# Discord JS using loop on message.channel.send

Tags: javascript, discord.js

After an event, I want my bot  to send multiples embed message in a loop, after each send a lot of actions are performed. Message embeds are declared in a constant outside the loop, but I can't loop and I don't know if it's possible to do...

```
const MESSAGENUMBER1 = {
  title: 'title1',
}
const MESSAGENUMBER2 = {
  title: 'title2',
}


        for (let j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
        message.channel.send({embed: MESSAGENUMBER[j]}).then((msg) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
          //etc
          }
        }
```

And I have this error :

```
ReferenceError: MESSAGENUMBER is not defined
```

Comment: `[j]` grabs elements of an array not a numbered variable.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all the `MessageEmbeds` in an `Array` instead:

```js
const messages = [
  {
    title: 'title1',
  },
  {
    title: 'title2',
  },
];

for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  console.log(messages[i]);
};
```